# rasbery pi ubuntu21.10 apache2 server operation on desktop. I got an error when I upgraded to ubuntu22.04. I don't know where or how to fix it

Tags: apache2

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Apache/2.4.53 (Ubuntu) Server at hosizorahananosita.net Port 443

Comment: You will want to check your Apache log files in `/var/log/apache2`. As it stands, there is nothing actionable in the question to offer a suggestion beyond this 

Comment: Thank you  errer log is below
[Tue Apr 26 16:10:36.137403 2022] [php:warn] [pid 78971] [client 223.149.255.23:18210] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "host" in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 699
[Tue Apr 26 16:10:36.137441 2022] [php:warn] [pid 78971] [client 223.149.255.23:18210] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "scheme" in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/canonical.php on line 720
[Wed Apr 27 00:00:04.606439 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1082] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in those three lines that would result in an HTTP 500 code unless you've configured Apache to quit on warnings. However, as it's clearly a WordPress site, you may want to check on [the WordPress Q&A sister site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com) to see if anyone else has reported a similar issue.

Comment: Thank you. Try to do so.